# nodeJS Gameserver and Android Clients

Tags: android, node.js, client, server, pomelo

I googled yet a lot. Nothing matched my issues.

We want to have a NodeJS Gameserver.

You should be able to connect with Android as client. There should be "rooms" to go into, like tables.

We want to join 4 android clients in one room. They shall play a game and send some timestamps and urls to each other.

At the end of a round, we want them to leave that specific room they are in.

Do you have some suggestions for us, what would the best framework look like? Is there a framework to achieve that? Would Pomelo.js meet our customs?

We are all new to android-programming and server-side JS.

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: Yet i found that one interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156636/node-js-and-socket-io-creating-room

Answer (score 2):

If It will be a realtime game you can use socket.io + node.js. And for registering your users passport.js (also to integrate it with socket use passport.socketio)

With socket.io you can send events over websocket and clients can join rooms.

For Android socket.io client you can use https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java