# Socket.io rooms - sending and receiving the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am not really sure how to send and receive data using socket.io rooms.

This is my client side code:

```
var socket = io('https://the.url');

socket.on('connect', function() {

    console.log('Connected to the socket.');

});

socket.on("client5", function (data) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

And this is my server side code

```
var app        = require('express')();
var server     = require('http').Server(app);
var https      = require('https');
var fs         = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('path/to/key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('path/to/key', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
var io          = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);

// HTTP server listening on port
io.set('origins', '*:*');
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

});

httpsServer.listen(10000);
// Middle ware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Route
app.post('/anything', function (req, res) {
    io.emit('client5', req.body);
    res.end();
});
```

And this works fine. But this is not using the rooms. This code will just emit data to "client5" socket and on the client side I am able to receive that data using socket.on("client5").

What I want to do is have a group of people that will be joining different rooms.

So user A, B and C will come in and be added to room "First Room" and users D, E and F will be added to "Second Room".

How can I send and receive data between rooms?

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156636/node-js-and-socket-io-creating-room?rq=1). I think it has the answers you need

Comment: Some Steps to lead you in the right direction
1).To set up different rooms your going to need to write to file/useDB/ save it somewhere for reference 
2).Set up each user with a id/username so you have reference when they join a room. 
3).When a user enters a room save it to your db that they have 'entered' and send the chat data to their page of the room their in. 
4).Save the chat data to the db and if you want to send it to another room just take the element in the db and send it over to the other room

Comment: @Dennington-bear thanks for your advices, I have solved this problem,  I will post the solution soon

Comment: @zachu - where was the solution? 3 years after, a guy needed it